# How to Centre a Page Layout With HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and am attempting a very basic webpage layout from scratch.

I'd like to centre all elements of the page (nav, header, section, footer, etc.) and still retain a left-placed nav bar. I've set-up the page itself, but can't figure out how to centre is. I'm using float:left at the moment, so I assume that's my problem, but I don't know how else t make the layout work.

Here's the code:

```css
header {
 text-align: center;
 width: 960px;
}

nav {
 line-height: 30px;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
}

section {
 float: left;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 800px;
}

footer {
 background-color: gray;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 960px;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Test HTML Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
 </header>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <section>
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec est nunc, iaculis in mauris vitae, commodo ullamcorper lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas posuere in libero id dictum. Phasellus viverra rutrum mollis.</p>
 </section>
 <footer>
  Copyright 2016
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to set a width on your `body` and center it using `margin: 0 auto`.This will set the top/bottom margin to 0 and will automatically adjust the left/right margin so that your page is centered.

```
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This alone will mess up your current layout only because the width of the body (now 960px) is less than the total width of your `section` and `nav` elements (810px + 210px respectively, adding up to 1020px). So you just need to adjust these to be equal to or less than your body. Don't forget that your `padding` adds to your container width, hence the extra 10px.

```
section {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 740px;
}

nav {
    line-height: 30px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 190px;
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/off3v3ok/) of your current code with the above adjustments.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for the informative reply. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
body {margin: 0 auto}
nav {float: left}
```

The body selector will make everything centered, and since the nav bar selector is more specific than body selector the nav bar will go to the left.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to center, you would better place all material inside a `div`:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec est nunc, iaculis in mauris vitae, commodo ullamcorper lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas posuere in libero id dictum. Phasellus viverra rutrum mollis.</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Copyright 2016
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

and in you `CSS`:

```
.wrapper{
   width: 800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```